# Python regex: Can I edit the set of numerical characters (\d)?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to write a regex to insert a space between all non-numerical sequences and numerical sequences. For example:

```
"12Dollars" -> "12 Dollars"
```

My current solution looks like this:

```
string = re.sub(r'([\d]) *([^\d\W])', r'\1 \2', string)
```

However, now I realize I need to also account for the character "½", which is not considered a numerical character by regex.

Can I add ½ to `\d` somehow? (I figured that may be the cleanest way to handle this...)

Comment: Err no. Add it to or after the the [\d]. Actually this only matches a single digit so add a + before the 1/2.

Comment: You can use python's `str.isnumeric()` function for all numeric characters

Comment: Ok your current pattern matches 2D not 12Dollars.

Comment: What about `r'([\d½]) *([^\d½\W])'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually a sad fact that `\d` in Python 3.x, although Unicode-aware by default, is not matching all chars defined in the `\p{N}` category, it only matches what `\p{Nd}` matches, and `\p{Nl}` and `\p{No}` should be added manually if you need to match them.

[`\p{Nl}` can be defined](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7BNl%7D&abb=on&ucd=on&esc=on&g=&i=) as

```
[\u16EE-\u16F0\u2160-\u2182\u2185-\u2188\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303A\uA6E6-\uA6EF\U00010140-\U00010174\U00010341\U0001034A\U000103D1-\U000103D5\U00012400-\U0001246E]
```

[`\p{No}` can be defined](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7BNo%7D&abb=on&ucd=on&esc=on&g=&i=) as

```
[\u00B2\u00B3\u00B9\u00BC-\u00BE\u09F4-\u09F9\u0B72-\u0B77\u0BF0-\u0BF2\u0C78-\u0C7E\u0D58-\u0D5E\u0D70-\u0D78\u0F2A-\u0F33\u1369-\u137C\u17F0-\u17F9\u19DA\u2070\u2074-\u2079\u2080-\u2089\u2150-\u215F\u2189\u2460-\u249B\u24EA-\u24FF\u2776-\u2793\u2CFD\u3192-\u3195\u3220-\u3229\u3248-\u324F\u3251-\u325F\u3280-\u3289\u32B1-\u32BF\uA830-\uA835\U00010107-\U00010133\U00010175-\U00010178\U0001018A\U0001018B\U000102E1-\U000102FB\U00010320-\U00010323\U00010858-\U0001085F\U00010879-\U0001087F\U000108A7-\U000108AF\U000108FB-\U000108FF\U00010916-\U0001091B\U000109BC\U000109BD\U000109C0-\U000109CF\U000109D2-\U000109FF\U00010A40-\U00010A48\U00010A7D\U00010A7E\U00010A9D-\U00010A9F\U00010AEB-\U00010AEF\U00010B58-\U00010B5F\U00010B78-\U00010B7F\U00010BA9-\U00010BAF\U00010CFA-\U00010CFF\U00010E60-\U00010E7E\U00010F1D-\U00010F26\U00010F51-\U00010F54\U00011052-\U00011065\U000111E1-\U000111F4\U0001173A\U0001173B\U000118EA-\U000118F2\U00011C5A-\U00011C6C\U00011FC0-\U00011FD4\U00016B5B-\U00016B61\U00016E80-\U00016E96\U0001D2E0-\U0001D2F3\U0001D360-\U0001D378\U0001E8C7-\U0001E8CF\U0001EC71-\U0001ECAB\U0001ECAD-\U0001ECAF\U0001ECB1-\U0001ECB4\U0001ED01-\U0001ED2D\U0001ED2F-\U0001ED3D\U0001F100-\U0001F10C]
```

Use

```
[0-9\u16EE-\u16F0\u2160-\u2182\u2185-\u2188\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303A\uA6E6-\uA6EF\U00010140-\U00010174\U00010341\U0001034A\U000103D1-\U000103D5\U00012400-\U0001246E\u00B2\u00B3\u00B9\u00BC-\u00BE\u09F4-\u09F9\u0B72-\u0B77\u0BF0-\u0BF2\u0C78-\u0C7E\u0D58-\u0D5E\u0D70-\u0D78\u0F2A-\u0F33\u1369-\u137C\u17F0-\u17F9\u19DA\u2070\u2074-\u2079\u2080-\u2089\u2150-\u215F\u2189\u2460-\u249B\u24EA-\u24FF\u2776-\u2793\u2CFD\u3192-\u3195\u3220-\u3229\u3248-\u324F\u3251-\u325F\u3280-\u3289\u32B1-\u32BF\uA830-\uA835\U00010107-\U00010133\U00010175-\U00010178\U0001018A\U0001018B\U000102E1-\U000102FB\U00010320-\U00010323\U00010858-\U0001085F\U00010879-\U0001087F\U000108A7-\U000108AF\U000108FB-\U000108FF\U00010916-\U0001091B\U000109BC\U000109BD\U000109C0-\U000109CF\U000109D2-\U000109FF\U00010A40-\U00010A48\U00010A7D\U00010A7E\U00010A9D-\U00010A9F\U00010AEB-\U00010AEF\U00010B58-\U00010B5F\U00010B78-\U00010B7F\U00010BA9-\U00010BAF\U00010CFA-\U00010CFF\U00010E60-\U00010E7E\U00010F1D-\U00010F26\U00010F51-\U00010F54\U00011052-\U00011065\U000111E1-\U000111F4\U0001173A\U0001173B\U000118EA-\U000118F2\U00011C5A-\U00011C6C\U00011FC0-\U00011FD4\U00016B5B-\U00016B61\U00016E80-\U00016E96\U0001D2E0-\U0001D2F3\U0001D360-\U0001D378\U0001E8C7-\U0001E8CF\U0001EC71-\U0001ECAB\U0001ECAD-\U0001ECAF\U0001ECB1-\U0001ECB4\U0001ED01-\U0001ED2D\U0001ED2F-\U0001ED3D\U0001F100-\U0001F10C]
```

Your [code fix](https://ideone.com/oemoNr):

```
import re
s = "ↂ12½Dollars"
pN = r'0-9\u16EE-\u16F0\u2160-\u2182\u2185-\u2188\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303A\uA6E6-\uA6EF\U00010140-\U00010174\U00010341\U0001034A\U000103D1-\U000103D5\U00012400-\U0001246E\u00B2\u00B3\u00B9\u00BC-\u00BE\u09F4-\u09F9\u0B72-\u0B77\u0BF0-\u0BF2\u0C78-\u0C7E\u0D58-\u0D5E\u0D70-\u0D78\u0F2A-\u0F33\u1369-\u137C\u17F0-\u17F9\u19DA\u2070\u2074-\u2079\u2080-\u2089\u2150-\u215F\u2189\u2460-\u249B\u24EA-\u24FF\u2776-\u2793\u2CFD\u3192-\u3195\u3220-\u3229\u3248-\u324F\u3251-\u325F\u3280-\u3289\u32B1-\u32BF\uA830-\uA835\U00010107-\U00010133\U00010175-\U00010178\U0001018A\U0001018B\U000102E1-\U000102FB\U00010320-\U00010323\U00010858-\U0001085F\U00010879-\U0001087F\U000108A7-\U000108AF\U000108FB-\U000108FF\U00010916-\U0001091B\U000109BC\U000109BD\U000109C0-\U000109CF\U000109D2-\U000109FF\U00010A40-\U00010A48\U00010A7D\U00010A7E\U00010A9D-\U00010A9F\U00010AEB-\U00010AEF\U00010B58-\U00010B5F\U00010B78-\U00010B7F\U00010BA9-\U00010BAF\U00010CFA-\U00010CFF\U00010E60-\U00010E7E\U00010F1D-\U00010F26\U00010F51-\U00010F54\U00011052-\U00011065\U000111E1-\U000111F4\U0001173A\U0001173B\U000118EA-\U000118F2\U00011C5A-\U00011C6C\U00011FC0-\U00011FD4\U00016B5B-\U00016B61\U00016E80-\U00016E96\U0001D2E0-\U0001D2F3\U0001D360-\U0001D378\U0001E8C7-\U0001E8CF\U0001EC71-\U0001ECAB\U0001ECAD-\U0001ECAF\U0001ECB1-\U0001ECB4\U0001ED01-\U0001ED2D\U0001ED2F-\U0001ED3D\U0001F100-\U0001F10C'
rx = r'([{0}]) *([^{0}\W])'.format(pN)
s = re.sub(rx, r'\1 \2', s)
print(s)                    # => ↂ12½ Dollars
```

Answer (score 0):

in regex, because the `[ ]` mean an `OR` operation for the characters inside, you could easily add your `½` to your regex:

```py
string = re.sub(r'([\d½]) *([^\d½\W])', r'\1 \2', string)
```

and if your old regex does what you wish without the `½` , this will do it for you.

hope this helps.